# Android, show activity, download image and show on imageview (in that order)

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to solve this, right now I have a Details Page activity (which loads dinamically from the DB depending on the item that was selected from a ListView). Each Details page can have between 1 and 5 images,  which are downloaded from an online server. The problem I have is that the activity is not showing until the pictures were downloaded.

Basically the activity won't show until onCreate finishes. I'm using a thread to download the image so the UI doesnt freeze, My question is, where could I download and set the ImageView to the downlaoded bitmap so the user will see the activity and information straight away after clicking on the list item and then download and set the image after downloaded?.

I tried putting the thread on the onResume but I think it doesnt help either. What would be the best way?

Regards,

George

Comment: Create AsyncTask class, in onPreExecute() method start a progress dialog, in doInBackground() method download all images and put it in imageviews and at last in onPostExecute() show activity.

Comment: problem is i need to 1st show the activity, then download and show the images, otherwise the user got to wait 4-5 seconds before the activity actually shows up, will this fire up the activity even before the images were fully downloaded?

Comment: @George please see my updated answer. Hope that clarifies a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Which executes on a background thread and prevents blocking of the main thread. You simply create a class that extends AsyncTask like below

**EDIT** - Yes, this will display your Activity even before the images get downloaded. You simply call the execute() method of your AsyncTask in onCreate() Have a look at the page on AsyncTasks above for a complete overview. It's really simple to implement you just need to be aware of configuration changes if your AsyncTask has not completed.

You might also want to  look into [caching](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) your bitmaps in memory to prevent them from being unnecessarily downloaded again.

```
public class DownloadItemDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Bitmap>{

protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(String...params){

 //Download each Bitmap here, and add them to a list to be displayed later


}

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Bitmap> results){

  //This method executes on the main thread, so after your downloads finish
  //You can set your imageviews in your Details Page here


}
```

}

Comment: I ended up doing it a bit different, since I'm using C# with xamarin what I did was to start the Thread on OnCreate and then on the Thread I use  

RunOnUiThread (() => setImage (thisBusiness.logo));

and setImage just sets it in the normal way, works well. But since it was your answer what took me on the right path I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your curiosity to make user happy, I think you have to use [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library from Github. This library provide you asynchronous image loading, caching and displaying.

You can also use [ShutterBug - Remote Image Loader](https://github.com/applidium/Shutterbug) from Github for same. It also fetch remote images and cache them. It is particularly suited for displaying remote images in lists, grids, and maps.